# Trying to concatenate a string with what I think is an unicode suffix

Tags: swift, swift5

I have this app of mine that reads datamatrix barcodes from drugs using the camera.

When it does for a particular drug, I receive this string from the detector, as seen on Xcode console:

```
0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX\U0000001d91D1
```

my problem is that `\U0000001d91D1` part.

This code can be decomposed on the following:

```
01 00000000D27267 17 211231 10 700XXXX \U0000001d 91D1"

01 = drug code
17 = expiring date DMY
10 = batch number
The last part is the dosage rate
```

Now on another part of the application I am on the simulator, with no camera, so I need to pass this string to the module that decomposes the code.

I have tried to store the code as a string using

```
let code = "0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX\U0000001d91D1"
```

it complains about the inverted bar, so I change it to double bar

```
let code = "0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX\\U0000001d91D1"
```

the detector analyzes this string and concludes that the batch number is `700XXXX\U0000001d91D1`, instead of just `700XXXX`, so the information contained from the `\` forward is lost.

I think this is unicode or something.

How do I create this string correctly.

Comment: Do you need the last part after the `\\`?

Comment: yes............

Comment: I'm still just unsure what you are looking for exactly (maybe give example of input & output)

Comment: the decoder receives this from the camera `0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX\U0000001d91D1`. Now I am trying to send the decoder the same string using a variable, without the camera.

Comment: "concludes that the batch number is `700XXXX\U0000001d91D1`, instead of just `700XXXX`" did you mean the other way around?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use string transform to decode your hex unicode characters:

```
let str1 = #"0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX\U00000DF491D1"#
let str2 = #"0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX\U0000001d91D1"#
let decoded1 = str1.applyingTransform(.init("Hex-Any"), reverse: false)!  // "0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX෴91D1"
let decoded2 = str2.applyingTransform(.init("Hex-Any"), reverse: false)!  // "0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX91D1"
```

---

You can also get rid of the verbosity extending `StringTransform` and `StringProtocol`:

```
extension StringTransform {
    static let hexToAny: Self = .init("Hex-Any")
    static let anyToHex: Self = .init("Any-Hex")
}
```

---

```
extension StringProtocol {
    var decodingHex: String {
        applyingTransform(.hexToAny, reverse: false)!
    }
    var encodingHex: String {
        applyingTransform(.anyToHex, reverse: false)!
    }
}
```

---

Usage:

```
let str1 = #"0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX\U00000DF491D1"#
let str2 = #"0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX\U0000001d91D1"#
let decoded1 = str1.decodingHex  // "0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX෴91D1"
let decoded2 = str2.decodingHex // "0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX91D1"
```

Comment: SIMPLY BRILLIANT! Cannot upvote you enough. `str1.applyingTransform` did the trick for me. Can you please explain what `applyingTransform` is doing?  Apple did not care to explain that API on their crappy documentation. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The `\U0000001d` substring probably represents code point U+001D INFORMATION SEPARATOR THREE, which is also the ASCII code point GS (group separator).

In a Swift string literal, we can write that code point using a Unicode escape sequence: `\u{1d}`. Try writing your string literal like this:

```
let code = "0100000000D272671721123110700XXXX\u{1d}91D1"
```